# Let $V$ be a 10-dimensional vector space having 7-dimensional subspaces $X,Y,Z\subset V$

Tags: linear-algebra, proof-writing

Show that there is at least one nonzero vector $x\in X$ such that $x\in Y$ and $x\in Z$.

I'm having a hard time showing that the intersection of three 7-dimensional subspaces of a 10-dimensional space is non-empty. I know that $$dim(U+V)=dim(U)+dim(V)-dim(U\cap V)$$ so applying that to three spaces, we get $$dim(X+Y+V)=dim(X)+dim(Y+Z)-dim(X\cap (Y+Z))$$ And since the dimension of the sum of subspaces is the minimum dimension of a subspace containing them, we can rewrite this as $$10\geq dim(X)+dim(Y)+dim(Z)-dim(Y\cap Z)-dim(X\cap(Y+Z))\geq7$$
$$10\geq7+7+7-dim(Y\cap Z)-dim(X\cap(Y+Z))\geq7$$
$$3\geq14-dim(Y\cap Z)-dim(X\cap(Y+Z))\geq0$$
But I'm not sure where to go from here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We know that $\operatorname{dim}(U \cap V)=\operatorname{dim}(U)+\operatorname{dim}(V)-\operatorname{dim}(U+V)\geq7+7-10=4$

Thus $\operatorname{dim}(U\cap V \cap W)= \operatorname{dim}((U \cap V) \cap W)=\operatorname{dim}(U\cap V)+\operatorname{dim}(W)-\operatorname{dim}((U\cap V)+W)\geq 4+7-10=1$

Answer (score 2):

Consider the natural map
$$\phi:V\to(V/X)\oplus(V/Y)\oplus(V/Z).$$
The kernel of $\phi$ is $X\cap Y\cap Z$. But $\phi$ is a map from a
$10$-dimensional space to a $9$-dimensional space, so it kernel
has dimension at least one.